# display datepicker inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am trying to use two date picker inside bootstrap modal, it works fine in firefox but not in chrome.

code for modal is

```
<div class = "modal fade" id="add" role="dialog">
<div class = "modal-dialog">
<div class = "modal-content">
<div class = "modal-header">
<h4> Add </h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="admin_add_coupon.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Expiration Date:</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="input-group date">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="expdate">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>                              
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
<div class="submit">
<input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit" name="submit">

<span></span>
</div>  
</div>                          

</form> 
</div>  

<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </a>

</div>
</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

js code is

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    startDate: "2012-01-01",
    endDate: "2015-01-01",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });
    </script>
```

when i use the code in chrome the date is not displayed properly. Can anyone plz tell why chrome is not supporting the code

Comment: can you add a fiddle

Comment: Why is your `datepicker` being assigned to a `div`? It should be assigned to an `input`.

Comment: Some widgets need to be visible on initialisation. I can't see why Chrome should differ from FF but it may be just an order of initialisation issue. Make sure that the date picker is initialised before its container is made modal.